# How do I prove that the branch of $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ which is in the first quadrant has no line of symmetry?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to prove that the curve  $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ has no line of symmetry. Through some coordinate geometry, I worked out that the  reflection of $(x_0,y_0)$  in the line $y=ax+b$
is   $$(x' , y' )=\left(\frac{2a(y-b)+(1-a^{2})x}{a^{2}+1},\frac{(a^{2}-1)y+2ax+2b}{a^{2}+1}\right)$$

I then tried to show that there are no $a$ and $b$ such that $f(x')\equiv y'$, but this lead to some system of 10 equations (If I didn't make any mistakes in the tedious amount of algebra involved). Is there any other elegant way to prove this?

Comment: What about the line $x=0$?

Comment: One way is to consider $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} y'$.

Comment: Even function is symmetric about y-axis

Comment: @EeveeTrainer The actual question was asking about one in the first quadrant. I mistakenly forgot to mention that. Extremely sorry about that

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH What does it mean for an arbitrary line $y=ax+b$ to be "*in the first quadrant*"? Or, do you mean that the restriction of $f(x)$ to $\mathbb R^+$ has no axis of symmetry?

Comment: I have a little changed your title in other that there is no misunderstanding.

Comment: You must mean orthogonal symmetry, not slant symmetry ?

Comment: Why 10 equations? You should get an infinite amount of equations (one for each $x_0$) with two unknowns ($a$ and $b$). If you can take any three of those infinitely many equations and show that they are inconsistent (i.e., that no $(a, b)$ satisfies all three), then you are done. Just as a sanity check: you should replace all $x$ and $y$ in the formula you have written by $x_0$ and $y_0$. Then replace $y_0$ by $1/x_0^2$. Then write $y' = 1/{x'}^2$, particularize at three different $x_0$, and show that the three equations are inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a remark by @wimi, here is a simpler proof:

Let us assume that such a symmetry $S$ exists.

The image of the horizontal asymptote $y=0$ by $S$ is still an asymptote. It is necessarily the other one $x=0$. We are in this way reduced to consider the symmetry with respect to line $y=x$.

But this would mean, by a classical property, that this branch of curve is the same as the corresponding branch of its **inverse function** $f^{-1}$; but the initial function given by $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ isn't equal to its inverse function given by equation $f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Contradiction.

Comment: Did you mean $\frac{1}{9}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$ in the denominator of the last equation?

Comment: Yes, my bad.... Fixed now.

Comment: And also... does the asymptote argument not restrict us to just the line $y=x$, with $b=0$? The image of the asymptote $y=0$ is $x=-b$. (I would anyway leave the current derivation in the answer, as it is probably more useful to future readers than the two-line pure asymptote argument).

Comment: @wimi : in fact you are perfectly right !

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, but shouldn’t it be ‘inverse’ instead of ‘reciprocal’? Or does reciprocal function mean the inverse of the function only?

Comment: You ar right : I change it ; my confusion comes from the fact that in french the names are inverted.